# Is there a canonical question about Kings placing themselves in check?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Fairly often questions are asked which can be answered by "no, the king can not be in check while it is not your turn" ([this one](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/can-king-take-piece-end-up-threatened) for example).

Is there a question which answers these question in a general way which we can use to close the rest as duplicates? If not, should we create one?

Comment: A common theme in those questions seems to be whether pinned pieces can give check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question - [Moving king into check](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8315/moving-king-into-check) - has the clear unequivocal answer you are looking for.